# Visual Basic how to get to %appdata%

Tags: .net, vb.net, appdata

I'm working on a project in Visual Basic and it's going to store all the data in a folder in `%appdata%`. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 I already tried this:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(%AppData%\test"))
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Dim filePath As String

filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\test"
```

Answer (score 7):

Using VB.NET, you can find them conveniently located in the `My` namespace at:

```vb
My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.AllUsersApplicationData
My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.CurrentUserApplicationData
```

Check out the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.myservices.specialdirectoriesproxy.aspx) for more paths.